# Identity Service - error on CM

Tags: identity-server, content-management, login

On my local machine I have `Sitecore 10.2`, `XP0`. I have problem with Identity Service.
Upon entering the address:  .cm / sitecore, he is redirected to the page `<address>.cm/sitecore/login?Fbc=1`. I should have been redirected to Sitecore Identity. My Sitecore Identity instance works fine, shows no error, works in the browser and the login process looks fine there. The certificates look correct. I have an error in CM logs:

```
12636 09:17:52 ERROR Unable to reach an external identity provider.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseChallengeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Owin.Middlewares.GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
Source: System.Net.Http
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()



9840 09:17:52 ERROR Unable to reach an external identity provider.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseChallengeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Owin.Middlewares.GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
```

The configuration of Owin is basic (after installation) and looks correct - all addresses etc. are in my opinion as they should be. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

EDIT:
I added two files:
Sitecore.IdentitServer.Host.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <CertificateThumbprint>cert</CertificateThumbprint>
      <CertificateStoreLocation>LocalMachine</CertificateStoreLocation>
      <CertificateStoreName>My</CertificateStoreName>
      <SitecoreMembershipOptions>
        <ConnectionString>Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ebok.locl_Core;User ID=securityuser;Password=pass</ConnectionString>
      </SitecoreMembershipOptions>
      <AccountOptions>
        <PasswordRecoveryUrl>https://locl.sc/sitecore/login?rc=1</PasswordRecoveryUrl>
      </AccountOptions>
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://locl.sc</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
        <PasswordClient>
          <ClientSecrets>
            <ClientSecret1>secret</ClientSecret1>
          </ClientSecrets>
        </PasswordClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

And
Sitecore.Owin.Authencitaction.Identity.Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://locl.identityserver" />

    <settings>
      <!-- The URI of the IdentityServer provider. -->
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.Authority" value="$(identityServerAuthority)" />

      <!-- The internal authority of SI Server. Leave it empty if it is the same as FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.Authority.
           Example: http://sitecore.identity -->
      <!--<setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.InternalAuthority" value="" />-->

      <!-- The client identifier on the IdentityServer. -->
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.ClientId" value="Sitecore" />

      <!-- Fill the FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.CallbackAuthority setting if you need another host to receive callbacks from IdentityServer. It is useful for reverse proxy configuration. -->
      <!--<setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.CallbackAuthority" value="http://proxy" />-->

      <!-- The client identifier for the Resource Owner Password flow on the IdentityServer. -->
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerClientId" value="SitecorePassword" />

      <!-- Wheither HTTPS is required or not for the metadata address or authority -->
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.IdentityServer.RequireHttpsMetadata" value="true" />
    </settings>

    <services>
      <configurator type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.ServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" />
    </services>

    <pipelines>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.IdentityProviders.ConfigureIdentityServer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" id="SitecoreIdentityServer">
          <scopes hint="list">
            <scope name="openid">openid</scope>
            <scope name="sitecore.profile">sitecore.profile</scope>
          </scopes>
        </processor>
      </owin.identityProviders>
      <owin.initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.Initialize.InterceptLegacyShellLoginPage, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" patch:before="processor[@method='Authenticate']" resolve="true">
          <legacyShellLoginPage>/sitecore/login</legacyShellLoginPage>
        </processor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.Initialize.JwtBearerAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" patch:before="processor[@method='Authenticate']" resolve="true">
          <identityProviderName>SitecoreIdentityServer</identityProviderName>
          <audiences hint="raw:AddAudience">
            <audience value="$(identityServerAuthority)/resources" />
          </audiences>
          <issuers hint="list">
            <issuer>$(identityServerAuthority)</issuer>
          </issuers>
        </processor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.Initialize.LogoutEndpoint, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" patch:before="processor[@method='Authenticate']" />
      </owin.initialize>
    </pipelines>

    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProvidersPerSites>
        <mapEntry name="sites with the core and unspecified database">
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer']" id="SitecoreIdentityServer" />
          </identityProviders>
        </mapEntry>
        <!-- An example that maps a sub-provider of the Identity Server to the sites that are not mapped to the SitecoreIdentityServer. -->
        <!--
        <mapEntry name="all sites">
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd']" />
          </identityProviders>
        </mapEntry>
        -->
      </identityProvidersPerSites>

      <identityProviders>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.IdentityServerProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true">
          <caption>Go to login</caption>
          <domain>sitecore</domain>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="apply additional claims" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.ApplyAdditionalClaims, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" />
            <transformation name="name to long name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="name" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
            <transformation name="role to long role" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="role" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>false</keepSource>
            </transformation>
            <transformation name="set ShadowUser" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider" value="local" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/shadowuser" value="true" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
            <!-- owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn pipeline uses http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/cookieExp claim to override authentication cookie expiration.
                 'exp' claim value can be configured on Sitecore Identity server on the client configuration by IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds setting.
                 Note: Claim value is Unix time expressed as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z -->
            <transformation name="use exp claim for authentication cookie expiration" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="exp" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/cookieExp" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
            <transformation name="remove local role claims" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.RemoveLocalRoles, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" />
            <transformation name="adjust NameIdentifier claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.AdjustNameIdentifierClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" />
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
        <!-- An example of how to add an identity provider as a sub-provider of the Identity Server.
             The 'name' property must be in the following format: SitecoreIdentityServer/[AuthenticationScheme], where the 'AuthenticationScheme' equals the
             authentication scheme of an external identity provider that is configured on the Identity Server.

             Notes:
               1. The 'TriggerExternalSignOut' and 'Transformations' properties are inherited from the the Identity Server provider node and can not be overridden.
               2. To use a sub-provider, the 'Enabled' property of the Identity Server provider must be set to 'Enabled'. -->
        <!--
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Log in with Sitecore Identity: Azure AD</caption>
          <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
          <domain>sitecore</domain>
        </identityProvider>
        -->
      </identityProviders>

      <propertyInitializer>
        <maps>
            <map name="set Email" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
              <data hint="raw:AddData">
                  <source name="email" />
                  <target name="Email" />
              </data>
          </map>
          <map name="set FullName" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
              <data hint="raw:AddData">
                  <source name="name" />
                  <target name="FullName" />
              </data>
          </map>        
          <map name="set IsAdministrator" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
            <data hint="raw:AddData">
              <source name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
              <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
            </data>
          </map>
        </maps>
      </propertyInitializer>

    </federatedAuthentication>

    <sites>
      <site name="shell" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer" />
      <site name="admin" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)admin/SitecoreIdentityServer" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Confirm if you have set AllowedCorsOrigins in Config\Production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml in IdentityServer root folder.

Comment: I added this configuration to post, but I think, that here is everything good

Comment: Could you please try by adding all the host URL in AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1 pipe separated in Sitecore.IdentitServer.Host.xml and remove all other AllowedCorsOriginsGroups?

Comment: Actually I have one addres:            <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://locl.sc</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>

Answer (score 2):

Confirm if you have set `AllowedCorsOrigins` in `Config\Production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` in the IdentityServer root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          ...
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://host1|http://host1</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>https://host2</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup3>https://host3</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup3>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
          ...
```

Comment: I added this configuration to post, but I think, that here is everything good

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Gaurav and also you need to verify into your CM site **webroot** by going to the config

```
\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config
```

and check if it's set with the proper **identityserver** site value or not like below

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://youtsiteidentityserver.dev.local" />
```

Then you need to go to your **identityserver** site **webroot** and go to the config

```
\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml
```

And check that @Gaurav Suggested.

Thanks

Comment: I added this configuration to post, but I think, that here is everything good

Comment: @JanNowak Go to your `connectionstring.config` and check that `sitecoreidentity.secret` is matching with your `ClientSecret1` key in the `\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file.

Comment: They are the same

Comment: @JanNowak Can you check that your identity server is bound with your exact certificate in IIS?

Comment: The certificates are the same in IIS and in the configuration

Comment: @JanNowak Then I will suggest to find logs and you will get something about the issue. Please update here, so I can look.

Comment: @JanNowak I want you to check this also. Create a new self-sign-certificate and then bind it with your identify server. Because it may happen that your current certificate has a different domain. Follow this to create a new one. https://jesuissitecore.com/2020/10/15/install-a-ssl-certificat-to-your-sitecore-site/

Comment: I bet on a quick new virtual machine from Sitecore and it got over there without a problem, so the certifications were probably the problem

Comment: @JanNowak Great! I mentioned in the comments also related to the certificate. Do you want me to update the answer?